# Transformar coluna do dataframe em horas, minutos e segundos

Tags: python, dataframe

Estou tendo problemas para transformar uma coluna inteira numérica que está em segundos para o formato de

> horas:minutos:segundos

, por exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(900,4000,size=(10000, 1)), columns=list('A'))
```

Como eu poderia transformar todo esse df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá para usar o método to_timedelta()

```
df["A"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["A"], unit="S")
```